# Orchard custom page renders default widgets?

Tags: orchardcms

Still getting to know Orchard, I've now managed to create a custom default page using a module and routing rules.

Although Orchard properly shows my page, it also renders three what seem to be default widgets, with the headings "First Leader Aside", "Second Leader Aside", "Third Leader Aside". Ok so apparantly you need to overwite that default behaviour or something like that, but I can't figure out how.

So is there something wrong / missing with my module, or do I need to provide a setting or something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a widget is in the default layer, it will appear on every single page in the site. See http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Managing-widgets

You will need to put these widgets in a different layer that is defined by a rule that fits what you want.

Comment: Found it, thanks. I need some reading up on widgets and layers I think. :)